# How to construct an array field when not know it's length?

Tags: java, arrays

I have no idea how to do such thing, heres what I've tried:

```
public class Mage{
    private int hp;
    private int mp;
    private String type;
    private String weakness;
    private int numSpell;//the input will tell you how long the array will be
    public Mage(int ihp, int imp, String itype, String iweakness, int inumSpell, String[] ispells){
        hp=ihp;
        mp=imp;
        type=itype;
        weakness=iweakness;
        private String[] spells = new String[inumSpell];
        for(int i=0;i<ispells.length;i++){
            spells[i]=ispells[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Would you consider my guess to be correct? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: yes... it should work... did you even try running it?

Comment: You don't need `inumSpell`, you can `ispells.length` instead.

Comment: I'm not convinced you really need to guess.

Comment: What is `spells` for? Looks like it should be an instance variable (`private` access-modifier is not allowed with local variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it looks a bit strange for what you are doing, coz you can simply do a ispells.length to get the no of spells instead of passing another int for such purpose.  Anyway, here is what you should do base on your original code:

(a simplified version of your code)

```
public class Mage {
    private String[] spells;

    public Mage(int noOfSpells, String[] ispells) {
        spells = new String[noOfSpells];
        for (......) {
             // your for loop to copy from ispells to spells
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For people that left me a comment, I appreciate it too. Noobs ask noob questions, that's why they are called noobs. I was confused when i asked this question :P

Answer (score 0):

In the field, it will look like: `private int[] numSpell;` You were missing brackets.